# Return List Of Object from other form using dialog

Tags: c#, winforms

**First Form**

```
listExcelBonCmds = new List<ListExcelBonCmd>();
            using (var form = new importationBonCmd())
            {
                var result = form.ShowDialog();
                if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    listExcelBonCmds = dialogForm.listBonCmdFromExcel;
                }
            }
```

**dialog Form**

```
 public List<ListExcelBonCmd> MyList
        {
            get { return myListExcel; }
          
        }

  private void toolStripButton4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();

        }
```

i want to send List from dialogue form to main form but not working.
*any help !!*

Comment: Check if should it be: `listExcelBonCmds = dialogForm.MyList;`

Comment: Again, what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change List from private to Public in class